# How to capture on browser open new tab the target url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to catch the attribute of hyperlink with JavaScript or Jquery on browsers open new tab event?

lets say I have a hyperlink `<a href="http://example.com/something">MyLink</a>` and using right click on link and opening new tab should alert first  "`http://example.com`"

Comment: I'm rather certain that you can't do this. Perhaps if you explain your need for such a thing then we can help you figure out a work-around for your scenario?

Comment: I have a tracking tool which get's the top level domain on hyperlink click when it's happening on site and it's working good. I would like to extend the functionality of this. And one of my collegue was insisting that is possible to make with JavaScript I was skeptic and I said to myself I'm gonna make some researches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this is the best that I can come up with but it ain't pretty.

Have all the links on the page point to another page (we'll call it redir.html). redir.html is passed a parameter via the URL that defines what page it should then open, like `redir.html?page=www.example.com/something`. redir.html then executes whatever JavaScript you want, perhaps only if it was opened in a new tab/window. This can be detected by checking to see if `window.history.length === 1`.

*redir.html:*

```
<script>
function getParameter(param) {
            var val = document.URL;
            var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
            var n=url.replace(param+"=","");
            return n;
}
var page = getParameter("page");
if(window.history.length === 1)
{
    alert("I opened in a new tab or window");
}

window.location.href = page;
</script>
```

*Example anchor tag on source page:*

```
<a href="redir.html?page=http://example.com/something">My link</a>
```

(I got the `getParameter` function from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).)

Comment: @fefe, can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: If you're referring to https to http redirects, perhaps you could change `<a href="redir.html...">` to `<a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/redir.html...">`.

Comment: I made a html document and I've been packing the codes above. then calling http://localhost/test.html I won't get to the target page. is going to produce a 404 error page I have been trying to replace the top level domains protocol as well

Comment: n is returning every time /

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you didn't include the `?page=www.example.com` at the end of your link. Are you certain that you read the suggestion carefully? It's not that you'd add this code to your page *containing* the link, it's that you would link to a newly created page containing this code.

Comment: yah man thats it!! it should work. I have to test with dynamical contents. The concept is cool!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is only possible with writing a browser extension. You cant control this type of things with JavaScript.